# Can Akka (Scala) be used to create asynchronous persistent server?

Tags: multithreading, scala, asynchronous, akka

I want to write a multi threaded (accepting asynchronous requests, meaning it will create a new thread to process each request) and persistent (meaning, it is long lived, stateful, and will keep running) in Akka (Scala). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can use any database as persistence layer (preferably one that has an asynchronous driver), or you can use akka-persistence as persistence layer (there are persistence backends for e.g. mongodb, cassandra, kafka, ...)

Here is a really [nice demo app](https://github.com/hseeberger/reactive-flows) that shows a lot of concepts related to akka. It is a simple chat with an angular.js frontend and a lot of current technologies in the backend.

To get started, write some simple prototype, first with just akka http and akka actors, and then slowly add new things (sharding, persistence, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any reason why you shouldn't be able do this with Akka. In Akka you do not manage threads manually, this is just one benefit of the framework.

Just create a protoype.